# Switching the two active windows on two monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

at my new workplace, i have two different sized monitors, so having the important stuff on the bigger screen becomes more important.

I wondering if theres a hotkey/shortcut to just switch the two active/opened app/windows between the screens. So App X and Monitor A displays on Monitor B and App Y on Monitor B displays on Monitor A.

I tried some combos with <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>arrows</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>arrows</kbd> and googling that doesnt really result in much.

Cheers

Comment: Shift+Win+Arrows should work. Do you have the desired window in focus? Does anything happen at all when you use that combo or are you just looking for different behavior?

Comment: Yes that works, but only shifting one window to the other screen at a time. Id like them two switch both at the same time, but i get the feeling that requires a macro :)

Comment: I suppose there must be a way to define your monitors' layout using the CLI or PowerShell. If such thing is possible, you can create a script  that switches the monitors in the layout and map it to a shurtcut ...