# Switch windows to other screen and window from other screen to main screen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

What I want to have happen is when I hit a keyboard combination is for the window on top of Monitor 2 to go to Monitor 1 and the window on top of Monitor 1 to go to Monitor 2.

Someone had a [similar question here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1542762/switching-the-two-active-windows-on-two-monitors)

The recommendation there was to create a script to do that for you. I don't know how to do that. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: Do you always want to see the window that you switch away from, or is Monitor 2 a virtual monitor that you can't actually see? If so, consider something like TidyTabs, so you can basically group any window to a tab stack and see just one window but have the ability to switch easily.

Comment: Do you have only one window on each monitor (as "on top" is not defined)? If more than one window per monitor, how to choose one, or maybe choose all?

Comment: @LPChip The second monitor is an actual monitor.

Comment: @harrymc "on top" is the visible window. choosing all would work as most of the time i will just switch back.

Comment: If you can always switch to the other window by alt-tab once, you may be able to script this. Otherwise its going to be nearly impossible to figure out what the top-most window is going to be on your other screen, because any window can be set to the top-most window and a program specifically written for this purpose would mistake that window over the window you actually would want to move. But if not, then the following key sequence should do what you want: `alt-tab` `win-shift-left arrow` `alt-tab` `win-shift-right arrow`. You could program an auto-hotkey script to do that with one keypress.

Comment: I'll look into that

Comment: What are the resolutions of the two monitors? I assume they are arranged horizontally, so is the main monitor on the left?

Comment: @harrymc Monitor on is on the left (Monitor 2) Is 1600x900 and the monitor on the right (monitor 1) is 1920x1080

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> a couple times will move an active window to another monitor. I think it tries to un-maximize and/or split it to have the screen. You may have to also hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to maximize it

Here is some of the script pieces (powershell cmdlets) that COULD automate this for you after you modify it. The bit of code I don't have is HOW will it know WHICH two windows to switch? It could simply assume its the current window & the next window in Alt+Tab...

```
# https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/controlpanel-canonical-names
# https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=net-5.0
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
# hits tab key five times, then enter key twice
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB 5} {ENTER 2}")
Sleep 2 # wait 2sec then press Alt+F4
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{F4}")
```

Comment: That just moves one window. I want to move the one from each screen.

Comment: win + shift + left/right will move it a whole monitor, not just positions.

Comment: Yes, but it won't move the window from the other screen to the main screen.

Comment: Alt+Tab will switch focus to the other window. Repeat keys to move window. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a third-party product such as the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

I found a AutoHotkey script that switches all windows between the two monitors
and even takes care of different monitor properties, in the post of
[Swap all Windows between Monitors - Windows 10 Bug](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=68311).
This script takes care not to move the Windows 10 taskbar from the secondary monitor.

I only modified the script to change the key-combination for swapping the screens
to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
I can't test the script since I don't have two monitors.

I reproduce the script here:

```
; MonSwap - Swaps all the application windows from one monitor to another.
; v1.0.2
; Author: Alan Henager
;
; v1.0.1 - xenrik - Updated to use relative screen size when swapping
; v1.0.2 - boiler, masgo - exclude Windows 10 secondary monitor taskbar from being swapped

SetWinDelay, 0 ; This switching should be instant

; Set this key combination to whatever.
#s::
SwapAll:
{
  DetectHiddenWindows, Off ; I think this is default, but just for safety's sake...
  WinGet, WinArray, List ; , , , Sharp
  ; Enable the above commented out portion if you are running SharpE

  i := WinArray
  Loop, %i% {
     WinID := WinArray%A_Index%
     WinGetClass, ThisClass, ahk_id %WinID%
     if (ThisClass = "Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd") ; do not swap the secondary monitor taskbar
        continue
     WinGetTitle, CurWin, ahk_id %WinID%
     If (CurWin = ) ; For some reason, CurWin <> didn't seem to work.
     {}
     else
     {
        WinGet, IsMin, MinMax, ahk_id %WinID% ; The window will re-locate even if it's minimized
        If (IsMin = -1) {
           WinRestore, ahk_id %WinID%
           SwapMon(WinID)
           WinMinimize, ahk_id %WinID%
        } else {
           SwapMon(WinID)
        }
     }
  }
  return
}

SwapMon(WinID) ; Swaps window with and ID of WinID onto the other monitor
{
  SysGet, Mon1, Monitor, 1
  Mon1Width := Mon1Right - Mon1Left
  Mon1Height := Mon1Bottom - Mon1Top

  SysGet, Mon2, Monitor, 2
  Mon2Width := Mon2Right - Mon2Left
  Mon2Height := Mon2Bottom - Mon2Top

  WinGetPos, WinX, WinY, WinWidth, WinHeight, ahk_id %WinID%
  WinCenter := WinX + (WinWidth / 2)
  if (WinCenter >= Mon1Left and WinCenter <= Mon1Right) {
    
    NewX := (WinX - Mon1Left) / Mon1Width
    NewX := Mon2Left + (Mon2Width * NewX)

    NewWidth := WinWidth / Mon1Width
    NewWidth := Mon2Width * NewWidth

    NewY := (WinY - Mon1Top) / Mon1Height
    NewY := Mon2Top + (Mon2Height * NewY)

    NewHeight := WinHeight / Mon1Height
    NewHeight := Mon2Height * NewHeight
 
 } else {
    NewX := (WinX - Mon2Left) / Mon2Width
    NewX := Mon1Left + (Mon1Width * NewX)

    NewWidth := WinWidth / Mon2Width
    NewWidth := Mon1Width * NewWidth

    NewY := (WinY - Mon2Top) / Mon2Height
    NewY := Mon1Top + (Mon1Height * NewY)

    NewHeight := WinHeight / Mon2Height
    NewHeight := Mon1Height * NewHeight
  }

  WinMove, ahk_id %WinID%, , %NewX%, %NewY%, %NewWidth%, %NewHeight%
  return
}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, store the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I was going to make my own auto hotkey script. Not sure if this will work for me. I'll test it.